# Is that possible accuracy 100 and precision 90?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, classification, precision

my network classify test data to the 6 class. total accuracy with 300 epoch is 100% but precision per class is between 64% to 97%. Is that possible? How can i explain it or what is my problem?

Comment: Maybe you can include the whole confusion matrix in your question.

Comment: Is it possible? or it's wrong?

Comment: It's not possible to classify all samples correctly and some incorrectly at the same time. As I said, you should look at the whole confusion matrix.